# Arrayformula count how many cells in a row are less than cells in another row only if both are nonzero/nonblank

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif, array-formulas

I found this formula, `=arrayformula(sumproduct($C$24:$C$31<B$24:B$31))` but I need it to ignore if one or both cells are 0 or blank.

I've tried and, and `countifs`, but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
=arrayformula(sumproduct($C$24:$C$31<B$24:B$31))
```

I want a number 0-8 for counting how many cells in the particular row are less than the compared row, but (i.e. 0<25) needs to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF((C2:C < B2:B) * (C2:C<>0), 1, 0)))
```

[image: 0]